# Can very strong gravitational wave collapse into a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-waves

Can a beam of very focused gravitational wave collapse into a black hole as ordinary matter(particle or radiation) does?

Alternative question: can a black hole grow by absorbing gravitational wave as well as absorbing ordinary matter?

It has been puzzling me that whether gravitational wave is "real matter", since gravitational wave can possess energy and momentum, but it has no well defined stress tensor. That's how I came up with this question. If the answer is negative, that means gravitational wave still cannot be unified with matter, otherwise there may be a potencial theory to explain the energy and momentum of gravitational wave.

I have read the answers to a similar question. But I was concerned that the result of numerical calculation may be unreliable because of the error. I want a more rigorous proof. (I will check the articles later)

Comment: Irrespective of the answer, it's doubtful that such a strong gravitational wave could even be created. How would it leave the massive black holes that would be needed to create it? It seems to me that the most violent event possible are black hole mergers, but the total energy momentum of the waves should be suppressed by something like a factor of 1/c, at least. Just winging it here, of course.

Comment: http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/0805.3880

Comment: http://www.msri.org/workshops/522/schedules/4098

Comment: ["It has been suggested that there may even be a regime where a
third or more black holes are formed during the interaction of the two black holes before they scatter, essentially
due to the strong focusing of gravitational waves by the shock-fronts representing the boosted black holes."](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.1338v1.pdf#page=7) .

Comment: Excuce me, I haven't read the articles you presented carefully. But I don't trust the result of numerical relativity. I hope there is an analytical solution or a rigorous proof. Is the stringency discussed in these articles?

Comment: @Ballistics Not unless someone solved the two body or more problem in general relativity

Comment: @Horus Even there is no analytical solution it doesn't matter. It can still be proved mathematically without analytical solutions, for example the singularity theorems. I just wonder whether the result of numerical caculation is reliable?

Comment: @Ballistics Quite reliable and one can make it ever more accurate. Personally I would prefer an exact solution since it would encode everything though none exists currently.